# How to delete whole database and reset the change tracker with EF Core using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a server client architecture where the server provides a Rest API for the clients to synchronize the whole database data. They save  it to their local SQLite database. The model is in a shared project and can change sometimes. Therefore the clients need to update their local SQLite database schema. This of course only happens after updating client's software (database file stays unchanged).

It's  simply achieved by generally deleting the database file and recreating it afterwards.

```
_context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
_context.Database.EnsureCreated();

AttachNewDataFromServerToDatabaseContext(_context);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

The Rest API service is instantiated as singelton and uses always the same database context object. First synchronization works fine. But the next ones fail:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type '***' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{id:  ***}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

So the Change Tracker is still aware of the "old" entities although the whole database was deleted.

My thoughts about it:

- Instantiating a new data context every time the database is synchronized could  fix it because the Change Tracker starts at "zero" then. Not a good solution in my eyes.
- Would be great if EnsureDeleted also "resets" the Change Tracker or you could do it manually.

What do you think about it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> - Instantiating a new data context every time the database is synchronized could fix it because the Change Tracker starts at "zero" then. Not a good solution in my eyes.

I would rather say that this is the "right" solution. The context metadata (a.k.a. `Model`) by default is cached per context *type*, db connection is maintained by connection pooling and is opened /closed only when needed anyway. So the only benefit of reusing context instance is to avoid creating a several `DbSet` instances.

At the same time the tracker would keep a lot of "entity" instances and prevent them of being garbage collection without any need after the `SaveChanges` call. Not to count potential multithread access issues.

So IMHO that's the way to go - instantiate new context, do something with it and dispose it.

> - Would be great if EnsureDeleted also "resets" the Change Tracker or you could do it manually.

Indeed that would be great. But currently neither `EnsureDeleted` does that nor EF Core provides a *public* way to do it manually.

There is an internal way though, with the usual risk that it could be changed in some future EF Core version. Adding

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
```

would allow you to use something like this

```
_context.ChangeTracker.GetInfrastructure().ResetState();
```

probably before `_context.Database.EnsureDeleted();`. Which basically proves that you should really use the first option (new context).

**Update (EF Core 3.0):** `ChangeTracker` no more exposes `StateManager` even internally, so here we need

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
```

and respectively

```
_context.GetDependencies().StateManager.ResetState();
```

**Update (EF Core 5.0):** Thank to [Vaclav Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332404/vaclav-elias) in comments, now ChangeTracker expose a Clear() method to clear the DbContext of all tracked entities.

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

Comment: Heads up here, EF Core 5.0 introduces ChangeTracker.Clear() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew

Answer (score 5):

Below lines worked for me. Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6282

```
    context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);

    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```