# EF Core with SQLite on xamarin: how to delete database and rerun migrations by code

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, ef-core-2.2

it's possible in my app to reset the database so the synchronization from the server will download all the data again. Before using EF Core, I would just delete the database file and recreate it, now, with EF Core, I'm not sure what to do, if I do a EnsureDeleted, the .Migrate() doesn't work after. And if I manually delete the database file, the .Migrate() also won't work...

So, I have tried this:

```
using (var model = new XSModel(false, false))
{
    model.Database.EnsureDeleted();                    
}

using (var model = new XSModel(false, false))
{
    model.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Migrate throws:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.'
```

asdfsadfas

I have tried this:

```
var filePath = new Java.IO.File(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbname.db"));
if (filePath.Exists())
    filePath.Delete();

using (var model = new XSModel(false, false))
{
    model.Database.Migrate();
}
```

And with this migrate also throws:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.'
```

Comment: About delete sqlite database, I find one thread that may be helpful to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454624/how-to-delete-whole-database-and-reset-the-change-tracker-with-ef-core-using-sql

Comment: It sounds like the connection string isn't configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm doing it now in EF Core 3.x is this:

```
    public bool UpdateDatabase(bool ensureDeleted)
    {
        var success = true;
        if (ensureDeleted)
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = this.CreateScope(false, false))
            {
                unitOfWork.EnsureDeleted();
                unitOfWork.DbContext.GetDependencies().StateManager.ResetState();
                this.ContextDataSettings.IsFirstInitializationCompleted = false;

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = this.CreateScope(false, false))
                success = unitOfWork.MigrateDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!ensureDeleted)
            {
                this.UpdateDatabase(true);
                return success;
            }

            this._logger.Error(e, "Could not migrate");
            throw;
        }

        return success;
    }
```